# How do I add a marker on the center of the map using osmdroid

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am currently using 2 activities, the first will load the map and there will be a menu option called "add place" when this is clicked the user fills it in and then it is sent back to the main activity where it then adds a marker with this String. The problem is that I can only add a marker to a specific location where I define the latitude and longitude using GeoPoint. I want to be able to add the marker on the last location which the map was positioned. Could anyone give me any ideas as to how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get geopoint for current center of the map:

```
IGeoPoint point = mapView.getMapCenter()
```

And then use it for marker construction.